# Clickable barchart, where clicking on any bar would redirect to concern information page

Tags: charts, asp.net-charts

I`m making student progress tracking system, where I need to show the progress chart on every subject.

Here every bar represent the subject, while clicking on any bar(subject) would produce another chart that is showing the progress of that particular subject.

I want every bar of bar-chart click-able that I can fire the event by clicking on that, so any help on that?(I am using ASP.NET(C#) for development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily implement this with Flash or JavaScript version of [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com)

The charts are client-side so all you need to do on the server is generate your data in CSV or 
XML format and feed it to the charting controls.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to bind a click event to the chart by inserting in page_load the following code: `this.CT_RT_DB_Pt3_1.Click += new ImageMapEventHandler(Chart1_Click)`; And then add the `protected void Chart1_Click(object sender, ImageMapEventArgs e)` method inside the inherited page class, and use `e.PostBackValue` to specify the subject clicked..

Specify the postback value to be the xaxis label of the bar clicked in the .aspx file: `<asp:Series Name="Series1" PostBackValue="#AXISLABEL"></asp:Series>`

Comment: that's OK but what if i want to use other value than #VALX and #VALY http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743390/pass-other-value-than-valx-and-valy-in-postback-of-series-to-get-value-on-char