# pass other value than #VALX and #VALY in postback of series to get value on chart click event 

Tags: asp.net, parameters, click, asp.net-charts

I am using asp.net chart control and i want to use chart click event to get the `deptId` value of bar click  in bar chart .

```
  <Series>                       
                        <asp:Series Name="Tour" ChartType="Column" ChartArea="MainChartArea"  PostBackValue="#VALX">
                        </asp:Series>
                        <asp:Series Name="Inspection" ChartType="Column" ChartArea="MainChartArea" PostBackValue="#VALX">
                        </asp:Series>
                        <asp:Series Name="NightHalt" ChartType="Column" ChartArea="MainChartArea" PostBackValue="#VALX">
                        </asp:Series>
                    </Series>
```

I am using department name to show on X axis but i want to capture `deptid` on chart click event . In above markup i use  `#VALX`  in series `postback` event but its give me deptname in click event

```
  protected void AllDepartmentComparisonBarChart_Click(object sender, ImageMapEventArgs e)
        {
            e.PostBackValue;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try removing your serie-level PostBackValue and try to iterate through the DataPoints of your Series, setting the correct deptId as PostBackValue for each individual DataPoint.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties.postbackvalue.aspx